# Netty, throttling HTTP requests, is it possible to hold them open for long periods of time from the server side?

Tags: java, netty

I'm working on a server process which receives files via HTTP PUT. The requests come from devices automatically throughout the day, not users. I currently handle everything in memory for performance reasons, but resort to writing the files to disk for later processing when I need to throttle. I'd like to leave writing to disk as a last resort, instead,'d love to have the option to throttle them by holding the connection open, and not receiving any data until I'm ready, for maybe 5-10 minutes. Can I do this from the server side with Netty?

Thanks for any thoughts or ideas

Answer (score 0):

You can use Channel.setReadable(false) to prevent any new read from the Channel. Once you are ready again you must call Cannel.setReadable(true) again.